# Angular | Create MDL component dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design

Referring to MDL web site: http://www.getmdl.io/started/index.html#dynamic it's recommended to use the function: componentHandler.upgradeElement(ctrlNode); when the component is added dynamically. However, in my scenario, I'm creating dynamically the components using Angular. The upgrade doesn't work for "children" because the parent has been already upgraded after the page is loaded.

Even though, using upgradeAllRegistered() or upgradeDom() it doesn't go through the new elements for the same reason.

I could find a workaround by removing the class/attribute "data-upgraded". But, I'm not so comfortable with this solution as it might result leak of memory.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks;

Omar

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: You can consider the official [material2](https://github.com/angular/material2) provided by Angular team.

Long answer:

Generally, touching native dom in Angular2 is not recommended. Angular2 is designed to be a platform-agnostic, dom-trasnparent framework. Developer need not, and should not, care about native element in Angular2, because it has done much to provide change detection, dom manipulation, view-data synchronization and etc.

While MDL is a library based on dom, it is more like bootstrap than angularjs.

So, these two are inherently not incompatible with each other. If you are just using styles in MDL, it might work in tandem. But JavaScript in MDL cannot work well with Angular unless you  make much effort to create your own component.

Comment: I agree! However, Material2 is still in its first beginning, there are no such basic components yet. I'm looking forward that Material2 becomes so rich as much as Material1.

Answer (score 0):

In the same scenario above, i did this by making each of my parent->child component implement `OnInit` Interface and used the lifecycle hook method `ngOnInit()` to call the `componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();`. A sample from my source : 
**DashBoard Component (Parent)**

```
@Component({
    templateUrl : './app/dash/dashboard.html',
    directives : [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,MenuComponent],
    Encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation.NONE
})


   export class DashBoard implements OnInit{
        userFullname : string;
        imagePath : string;

        constructor(private _router : Router){}

        ngOnInit() {
            this.imagePath = 'app/dash/avatar.png';
            componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
            this.userFullname = localStorage.getItem('user');
        }
    }
```

Then the **Menu Component (Child)**

```
@Component({
    selector : 'menu-pane',
    templateUrl : './app/dash/menu/menu.html',
    providers : [HTTP_PROVIDERS,MenuService],
    directives : [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class MenuComponent implements OnInit{
    routesReady : boolean;

    routerView : any[];
    constructor(private menuServ : MenuService, private _router : Router){}

    ngOnInit(){
        componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
        this.routerView = [];
    }
}
```

i guess the snippets are bit confusing to figure out, but you could simply call the method in ngOnInit() of every component

Comment: Please don't do that. You'll probably break change detection or view encapsulation or other stuffs.